# How to create column based on previous value within the same group in pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below and want to create a column (date_fill) by filling the value in "date" column with the previous value **if the value in "name" column is the same**.

Input:

```
  name  group date
0    a     sdf  NaN
1    a     dss  NaN
2    a     fff  2022-10-23
3    b     ggg  NaN
4    b     few  NaN
5    b     mjf  NaN
6    c     ggj  NaN
7    c     ojg  NaN
8    c     ert  NaN
9    c     dfg  2022-11-03
```

Expected output:

```
  name  group date  date_fill
0    a     sdf  NaN  2022-10-23
1    a     dss  NaN  2022-10-23
2    a     fff  2022-10-23  2022-10-23
3    b     ggg  NaN  NaN
4    b     few  NaN  NaN
5    b     mjf  NaN  NaN
6    c     ggj  NaN  2022-11-03
7    c     ojg  NaN  2022-11-03
8    c     ert  NaN  2022-11-03
9    c     dfg  2022-11-03  2022-11-03
```

I have tried below, but it didn't work.

```
def date_before(df):
    if df['name']==df['name'].shift(-1):
        val = df['date'].shift(-1)
    else:
        val = np.NaN
    return val

df['date_fill'] = df.apply(date_before, axis=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A groupby with bfill might work

Comment: df['date_fill'] = df.groupby('name')['date'].bfill()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['date_fill'] = df.groupby('name')['date'].ffill()
```

ffill replaces null values with the value from previous rows, just group by name for your case

Answer (score 1):

```
 df = df.groupby('name')   
df['date_fill']=df['date'].ffill().shift(-1)
```